# Android KeyStore get raw bytes/string of stored key

Tags: android, encryption, key, android-keystore

I can generate a key to be stored in the Android Keystore like so:

```
private static final String AndroidKeyStore = "AndroidKeyStore";
private static final String AES_MODE = "AES/GCM/NoPadding";
keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(AndroidKeyStore);
keyStore.load(null);

if (!keyStore.containsAlias(KEY_ALIAS)) {
    KeyGenerator keyGenerator = KeyGenerator.getInstance(KeyProperties.KEY_ALGORITHM_AES, AndroidKeyStore);
    keyGenerator.init(
            new KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder(KEY_ALIAS,
                    KeyProperties.PURPOSE_ENCRYPT | KeyProperties.PURPOSE_DECRYPT)
                    .setBlockModes(KeyProperties.BLOCK_MODE_GCM)                   .setEncryptionPaddings(KeyProperties.ENCRYPTION_PADDING_NONE)
                    .setRandomizedEncryptionRequired(false) 
                    .build());
    keyGenerator.generateKey();
}
```

Similarly, I can retrieve it like so:

```
keyStore.getKey(KEY_ALIAS, null);
```

I know that the getKey() function returns a Key object, but I haven't found a way to reveal the key itself. It does not seem to have a toString() or getBytes() or something like that.

How can I get the bytes of the key, or at least print out the string version of it? Is it even possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The "AndroidKeyStore" is specifically designed to make this impossible or at least very difficult. There is a more complete discussion [here](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/keystore.html), but in summary:

> Android Keystore system protects key material from unauthorized use.
>   Firstly, Android Keystore mitigates unauthorized use of key material
>   outside of the Android device by preventing extraction of the key
>   material from application processes and from the Android device as a
>   whole.

Continuing along the lines of your example, the following additional lines of code:

```
Key key = keyStore.getKey(KEY_ALIAS, null);
String algorithm = key.getAlgorithm();
String format = key.getFormat();
byte[] encoded = key.getEncoded();
```

should cause key to be a valid non-null reference to Key object, `algorithm` should return "AES", but `format` should be `null` as should `encoded`.

Answer (score 0):

The Key object returned has methods:

```
getAlgorithm()
getEncoded()
getFormat()
```

They return String, byte[], and String, respectively.

Click [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/Key.html) for more info.